# Best way to break a string on the penultimate dot on C#

Tags: c#, string

Need to get substring from string from "1.2.3.4" to "1.2"
I have this solution:

```
string version = "1.2.3.4";
var major = version.Substring(0, version.Substring(0, version.LastIndexOf('.')).LastIndexOf('.'));
```

but it looks ugly.
what would be the best way to do this?
(note) initial string may be with different size like 11.22.33.44 or other

Comment: The delimiter is always the second dot?

Comment: As usual, what is your definition of _best_?

Comment: You could always set a proper assembly version and use the build-in Version property of every assembly to access the different parts of the version.

Comment: yes, the delimiter is always the second dot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var newstr = String.Join(".", "1.2.3.4".Split('.').Take(2));
```

Or maybe you want to use the [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

```
var ver = new Version("1.2.3.4");
Console.WriteLine(ver.Major + "." + ver.Minor);
```

Comment: Damn, glad I refreshed the page before I posted my answer, er, your answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
string version = "1.2.3.4";
Version ver = new Version(version);
```

And then you can combine `Major` and `Minor`

```
var major = string.Format("{0}.{1}", ver.Major, ver.Minor);
```

That would give you `"1.2"`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
string version = "1.2.3.4";
int pos1 = version.IndexOf(".");
if (pos1 >= 0)
{
    pos1++;
    int pos2 = version.IndexOf(".", pos1);
    if (pos2 >= 0)
    {
        version = version.Substring(0, pos2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use regex for these kind of parsing:

```
    string version = "1.2.3.4";
    string sub = Regex.Match(version, @"[1-9].[1-9]").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's another way to do it. Though you should probably use the `Version` class.

```
string version = "1.2.3.4";

int indexOfFirstDot = version.IndexOf('.', 0);
int indexOfSecondDot = version.IndexOf('.', indexOfFirstDot+1);

string majorAndMinorVersion = version.Substring(0, indexOfSecondDot);
```